# MemoryError when closing program while dumping with pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I often close my program while It's dumping a dictionary using pickle. When I open the program, It raises MemoryError. I mean that It happens JUST if I close the program EXACTLY WHEN It's dumping. IMHO, It happens because the program doesn't save all the dictionary on time, and when I close the program, the file remains unreadable. In other words, IMHO, the program doesn't complete on time "dump" procedure and file is corrupted. But I'm not sure.
I use the following function to dump the dictionary:

```
def saveMemory(dictionary, filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as output:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: How are you closing the program? `Ctrl-C`? `Ctrl-Alt-Esc`?

Comment: Easy solution: have patience and wait until the dump completes.  More technical solution: dump in a spawned subprocess.